# Cannot upgrade SVN - Can't open directory ./svn/text-base No such file or directory

Tags: svn

There seems to be a infinite loop of troubles here which I don't know how to overcome.

I have this directory which used to be under SVN 1.6 so now when I do `svn status` I'm advised to upgrade SVN which makes sense. Strangely, when I run `svn upgrade` I got an error:

```
[root@141-16 src]# svn upgrade
svn: E000002: Can't open directory '[current directory]/.svn/text-base': No such file or directory
```

How am I supposed to solve this problem?

`svn status` output:

```
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: Working copy '[current directory]' is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)
```

My SVN version is 1.7.11

Comment: You could try doing an `svn cleanup` on the checkout before running `svn upgrade`. Otherwise, if it's not too onerous, do a fresh checkout of your project with SVN 1.7.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem when I was messing with some old work.  I used the find command: `find . -type d -name .svn -exec mkdir {}/text-base \;` to automatically make all of those directories.

Comment: You need a "." after find, but this worked perfectly.  I did also have to chmod all the .svn directories to 774.

Comment: I have this directory + I changed the rights of .svn and all sub-directories to 774. Nevertheless, `svn upgrade` fails with that error message.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too, and `svn cleanup` didn't help. What I wound up doing was creating all the directories it complained about not finding (just a plain `mkdir`, nothing else), then running `svn upgrade`. That seemed to work.

I switched to Git years ago, but this is a legacy project. I forgot how much Subversion annoys me by comparison. :P

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too and fixed it by continuously making `touch` with filename SVN missed.
After each `touch` make `svn clean` and then `svn up`. It should help

Answer (score 1):

I had slightly same error:

> svn: Can't open file 'XY/.svn/tmp/text-base/analyticstracking.php.svn-base': No such file or directory

Using `svn cleanup .` on the directory worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

text-base is not a file, the command svn upgrade expects this as a directory then:

```
mkdir .svn/text-base
```

and then

```
svn upgrade
```